# Success function does not return data using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, smarty, cs-cart

The success function does not give results. How do I solve this?

I have the following code

```
function fun()
{
  var list_target_id = 'year';
  $.ajax({
    url: '://localhost/htdocs/cscart_mutli_car/index.php?dispatch=drill.drill',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
}



if ($mode == 'drill')
{
  $id = 166;
  $arr = array('category_id' = > 167, 'category' = > 'computers');
  echojson_encode($arr);
  exit;
}
```

Here in this **Ajax** I get the success alert. But it **does not provide any results**. How do I solve this?

Comment: It's returned an object. What's wrong with that? What's in the object?

Comment: `[Object object]` is when you get when you stringify a plain object. You are returning a JSON representation of a pain object. `alert` only takes a string as input. You are getting the expected behaviour.

Comment: i need to get echo json_encode($arr); in success function

Comment: Use console.log to see the properties of your object. As said, you're passing an object to a method that only accepts strings.

Comment: You've got it! It's in an object which is correct, re-read all above comments.

Answer (score 1):

The `data` which is returned in the success handler is an Object.The alert will alert the string representation of the Object i.e. `data.toString()` which is `[Object object]`

You can get required things from `data` by calling properties from `data` object like this.

```
alert(data.category_id);
```

and

```
alert(data.category);
```

Comment: Its gives only undefined

Comment: Soniya, use console.log(data) to see the structure of your object.

Comment: Are you looking in your console, or expecting an alert to pop up?

Comment: i need to get category id and categoryname

Comment: Are you looking in your console, or expecting an alert to pop up?

Comment: I used this code JSON.stringify(data) . Its provides {"notifications":[],"text":"{\"category_id\":\"167\",\"category\":\"computers\"}"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68335/discussion-between-soniya-kaliappan-and-i-conica).

Comment: Soniya. We're at a critical point here, where I can't help you any more unless you answer the question. Don't just keep telling me what code you've used. You're refusing to acknowledge the existence of objects, even though in JavaScript everything is an object. You're going to have to get to grips with them. Are you, when running console.log(data), looking in your console for the output, or expecting it to alert you a string? Objects aren't strings, you want to see a representation of the object in a tree format, which console.log will show you.